# Laptop WIFI Issues on Docking Station with 16.04

Tags: wireless

I have a Dell Latitude E5430 on a Dell Pro3x docking station. I am using a single monitor at this point. WIFI is not working unless I open the laptop. I tested this with Windows 7 before installing Ubuntu.  Any ideas what I should look at or try?

Result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0082] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1681] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1028:053c]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Type `gksu gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Enter your password when prompted. You are now in the graphical editor for Ubuntu and looking at the systemd configuration file.

Search for the text:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=
```

ensure there is a **ignore** after the equal sign. For good measure remove the **#** at the beginning of the line if it's there.

Setting Docked status to ignore tells systemd not to suspend your laptop if it's plugged into a docking station or has a monitor/tv attached via HDMI port.

It sounds like your system is suspended or, at least partially suspended, with the lid closed.

Save the file and reboot.

This is the first thing to try. There are other issues such as stopping and restarting wifi during suspend/resume but this is a good first step. Please report back with results.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: If I come across anything else I'll update the answer. In the mean time hopefully other people offer ideas.